# Bolometer calibration - voltage and intensity

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, education

I am interested in possible hazards due to high intensy infrared light sources. Therefore I want to use the "PASCO TD-8553 radiation sensor" ([website](http://www.pasco.com/prodCatalog/TD/TD-8553_radiation-sensor/#overviewTab)) to measure the intensity of the radiation of an infrared light source. The bolometer outputs voltage values. In the user manual (see website) it says that these voltage values are proportional to the intensity of the radiaton - but I cannot find any equations or proportional constants in this document.

How can I calibrate a bolometer myself? Any experiences using this device?

Answer (score 1):

That is an educational tool. If you need to measure infrared light for safety reasons, you really should get a tool that was designed for measurement, not education. Just get a bolometer that is factory calibrated and displays in watts. For example, these: http://www.ophiropt.com/laser-measurement-instruments/laser-power-energy-meters/products/laser-power-meters

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could calibrate it using experimental data on page 20!